# Need Maximum Optimized custom binary array sort function in PHP

Tags: php, function, sorting, optimization, binary

Could you plese help me to create an optimized php custom function for sorting a binary array ? Now, I am using the bubble sort algorithm with two for loops. My code given below :

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++ )  
{  
   for ($j = 0; $j < $array_size; $j++ )  
   {  
      if ($numbers[$i] < $numbers[$j])  
      {  
         $temp = $numbers[$i];  
         $numbers[$i] = $numbers[$j];  
         $numbers[$j] = $temp;  
      }  
   }  
}
```

Comment: who voted this up? spam accounts?

Comment: This is not a question. Be or not to be - is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bubble sort in an `O(N^2)` you can use the below approach which is `O(N)`:

1. Find the sum of all elements in the array. It'll give you the number of `1`'s in the array. You can use the array_sum() function for this. Call the result `s`. Also let `n` be the number of elements in the array.
2. The sorted array will have `n-s` number of `0`s followed by `s` number of `1`'s.

Note that you can't do better than `O(N)` as you must touch each array element once.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I want a simple logic like this.

Comment: Some kind of super-optimized radixsort. +1